# Function application operand ($) for types in haskell?

Tags: haskell

Is there a ($) equivalent for types in Haskell?

If I have a type with parameters

```
data myType a b c = ...
```

It would be nice to apply a monad like so :

```
f :: input -> errorMonad $ myType a b c
{- throws error:
   Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘$’. -}
```

I can get the same effect with

```
f :: input -> errorMonad (myType a b c)
```

but is not as clear IMO.

Comment: Perhaps this can be done with the `TypeOperators` extension and `type ($) a b = a b`. I'm not sure this will have the right precedence, though.

Comment: @chi Your suggestion works. If you want to submit it as an answer I'll accept it. However Im still wonder if there is no built in operator for this. It seems like a no brainer!

Comment: Note that type names in Haskell have to have `CamelCase`. So `myType` is not a valid type name.

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/first-class-families-0.8.0.0/docs/Fcf-Combinators.html#t:-36-

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possible solution is to define your own type operator `$`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators, PolyKinds #-}

type ($) a = a
```

Comment: Better, I think: `type ($) a = a`.

Comment: Note that any solution should use `PolyKinds`.